# Which is the best way of using navigate function to handle the movements from one page to another

Tags: flutter, dart, android-intent, navigator

I am an android developer and now learning about flutter development. In flutter navigator is using to move one page to another like intents in android. While I am using navigate, the back is goes to the initial page.

Am using the below code for navigation.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => widget.user ? Dashboard() : Login()),
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Navigator.push(context)** for navigate from one page another using button, like the following:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const ScreenDashboard(),
    ),
  );
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigation in Flutter is implemented as stack, so when you are using function **Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement** navigator replaces your current page with new one. If you want to save previous page also, use **Navigator.of(context).push** instead

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#limitations) suggests using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package for Navigation.

> Flutter applications with advanced navigation and routing requirements (such as a web app that uses direct links to each screen, or an app with multiple Navigator widgets) should use a routing package such as **go_router** that can parse the route path and configure the Navigator whenever the app receives a new deep link.

---

##### Reference questions regarding go_router:

- [Flutter: go_router how to pass multiple parameters to other screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976031/flutter-go-router-how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-other-screen/74813803#74813803)
- [Go_Router Pass Object to new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74741283/go-router-pass-object-to-new-route/74813017#74813017)